# Update DataGridRow style when item added to collection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I have the selector control with 2 `DataGrid` `DataGrid` controls on it. The right one is a basic `DataGrid` and the left one is an `EntityDataGrid` based on the `DataGrid`. The user can select item in the `EntityDataGrid` and 'move' it to the `DataGrid`.

The problem is how to prevent adding already selected items. Since the `EntityDataGrid` has a custom items provider, I can't just use `CollectionViewSource`/`CollectionView` to filter selected items. So I decided to mark rows of the `EntityDataGrid` as disabled. But I can't figure out how to update a row state when the `DataGrid` bound collection have been changed.

Here is a xaml markup for the view:

```xml
<b:FormControl 
           ...
           x:Name="Self"
           d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:MoverViewModel}">
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:DisableSelectedItemsConverter x:Key="DisableSelectedItemsConverter" />
    </Grid.Resources>
    ...
    <dg:EntityDataGrid x:Name="EntityDataGrid" ItemsProvider="{Binding SelectingItemsProvider}">
        <dg:EntityDataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <!-- IsEnabled should be updated when the SelectedItems collection changes, but I can't figure out how to trigger it -->
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <!-- Converter code: !collection.Contains(item) -->
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DisableSelectedItemsConverter}">
                                <!-- item -->
                                <Binding />
                                <!-- collection -->
                                <Binding ElementName="Self" Path="DataContext.SelectedItems" />
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </dg:EntityDataGrid.RowStyle>
    </dg:EntityDataGrid>

    <DataGrid x:Name="SelectedItemsDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItems}" />
    ...
</Grid>
```

And here's a ViewModel:

```cs
public class MoverViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private EntityProvider _selectingItemsProvider;

    public MoverViewModel()
    {
        SelectItemCommand = new DelegateCommand(o =>
        {
            var item = o as drBaseWithId;
            SelectedItems.Add(item);
            SelectedItemsSet.Add(item);

        });
        DeselectItemCommand = new DelegateCommand(o =>
        {
            var item = o as drBaseWithId;
            SelectedItems.Remove(item);
            SelectedItemsSet.Remove(item);
        });

        SelectAllCommand = new DelegateCommand(_ =>
        {
            var item = new drBaseWithId() { IsStub = true };
            SelectedItems.Clear();
            SelectedItemsSet.Clear();
            SelectedItems.Add(item);
            SelectedItemsSet.Add(item);
        });
    }

    public DelegateCommand SelectItemCommand { get; }
    public DelegateCommand SelectAllCommand { get; }
    public DelegateCommand DeselectItemCommand { get; }
    public DelegateCommand DeselectAllCommand { get; }

    public EntityProvider SelectingItemsProvider
    {
        get { return _selectingItemsProvider; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _selectingItemsProvider)) return;
            _selectingItemsProvider = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectingItemsProvider));
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<drBaseWithId> SelectedItems { get; } = new ObservableCollection<drBaseWithId>();
    public HashSet<drBaseWithId> SelectedItemsSet { get; } = new HashSet<drBaseWithId>();
}
```